# Can't find directory and files created inside task

Tags: c#, .net, file, task-parallel-library

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
var path=@"D:\path";

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    DataSet dataset;

    //Some xml work to fill dataset...

    if(!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.Create(path);

    dataset.WriteXml(Path.Combine(path, "filename.xml");

    });
    tasks.Add(task);

}

while(tasks.Count>0)
{
    int i = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());
    tasks.RemoveAt(i);

    string[] files;
    files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
}
```

We are trying to get files for each task after it will finish its work. But the problem is, when the code comes to **Directory.GetFiles()** method, it could not find the releated path (Throws **DirectoryNotFound** exception). But when we look the path manually, there is a folder with xml files. Sometimes code can find the directory but returns no files even there is a file inside the folder. This situation continues till tasks count comes zero.

I also tried **Task.ContinueWith** but still not solved. It looks like synchronization problem because while debuging the code works correctly. Is it possible **Task.WaitAny** doesn't wait the task completion?

We are using .NET 4.0.

Comment: perhaps its because you are missing a \ between path + filename.xml?

Comment: That's why `Path.Combine` is recommended.

Comment: you dont add any task to `tasks`?

Comment: I think he did add all task to tasks but for some reason code snippet is not showing it....@aurvana please verify your code snippet

Comment: all the task will keep overriding same file??

Comment: Where the code that shows what you're doing with the `i` in `for(int i=0;i<8;i++)`?

Comment: Are you saying all iterations are writing to the same file?

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a backslash in your path, so when concatenating you're writing to

```
@"D:\path" + "filename.xml"
```

which is

```
@"D:\pathfilename.xml"
```

and NOT

```
@"D:\path\filename.xml"
```

Nothing to do with tasks at all there :)

Comment: `Path.Combine(path, "filename.xml");` is a standard way